# Unable to get pg_settings from non-postgres user

Tags: postgresql, cron, pg-cron

I have the following query to get the settings for `max_running_jobs`.

```
select *    
from pg_settings 
where name = 'cron.max_running_jobs';
```

I'm able to get the records from postgres user but not with the `non-postgres` user.

Any grant/permission I got missed?

Comment: Whats is the Postgres version and distribution ?

Answer (score 0):

by this REF: https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_settings.html

the permission should be:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON pg_settings TO PUBLIC;
```

you can confirm it running:

```
SELECT grantee, string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='pg_settings'   
GROUP BY grantee;
```

Comment: Better link to the official documentation

Comment: @AdelinoSilva, Still unable to access, after running `GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON pg_settings TO myuser;`

Comment: @MAK check if this user can run: SELECT * FROM pg_show_all_settings() AS A;